# Solving a differential equation analytically

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the question to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=1-y^2$ analytically, I'm looking at last year's example where the question is to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=y-y^2$ and they've done this:

> Solving the equation will require the following formula
>   $$\int_{y_0}^y\frac{dz}{z(1-z)}=\int_{x_0}^xds=x-x_0$$
>   provided that $y,y_0\ne0,y,y_0\ne1$. Hence
>   $$\ln\left|\frac y{y_0}\right|-\ln\left|\frac{y-1}{y_0-1}\right|=x-x_0.$$
>   Noticing that (a) solutions of autonomous equations with continuous RHSs are monotone, and (b) the RHS is differentiable, we can conclude that solutions of the initial value problem above are always sandwiched between two equilibrium solutions $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=1$. In this case the above equality becomes
>   $$\ln\frac y{y_0}-\ln\frac{y-1}{y_0-1}=x-x_0,$$
>   or alternatively
>   $$\ln\frac y{y-1}=x-x_0+\ln\frac{y_0}{y_0-1}.$$
>   Therefore
>   $$\frac y{y-1}=e^{x-x_0}\frac{y_0}{y_0-1}\implies y(x)=\left(1+e^{-(x-x_0)}\frac{1-y_0}{y_0}\right)^{-1}$$
>   is the solution of the initial value problem.

I follow it all up until the last line, specifically the part where they change it to
$$y(x)=\left(1+e^{-(x-x_0)}\frac{1-y_0}{y_0}\right)^{-1}$$
All help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Your equation is Separable. Separate and integrate using partial fractions.

Comment: I can't format very well but I get y = ((e^c)+2t+1))/((e^c)+2t-1), should my ts become xs as I've done dy/dx not dy/dt, and I need it in a format similar to the answer last year but I have cs and ts and they have xs, ys, x_0s and y_0s

Answer (score 1):

Clarification of the last step:

\begin{align}
& \dfrac{y}{y - 1} = e^{x - x_0}\dfrac{y_0}{y_0 - 1} \\
\implies & \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{y}{y - 1}} = \dfrac{1}{e^{x - x_0}\dfrac{y_0}{y_0 - 1}} \\
\implies & \dfrac{y - 1}{y} = e^{-(x - x_0)} \dfrac{y_0 - 1}{y_0} \\
\implies & 1 - \dfrac{1}{y} = e^{-(x - x_0)} \dfrac{y_0 - 1}{y_0} \\
\implies & 1 - e^{-(x - x_0)} \dfrac{y_0 - 1}{y_0} = \dfrac{1}{y} \\
\implies & \dfrac{1}{y} = 1 + e^{-(x - x_0)} \dfrac{1 - y_0}{y_0} \\
\implies & y = \left( 1 + e^{-(x - x_0)} \dfrac{1 - y_0}{y_0} \right)^{-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac y {y-1} & = A \\[10pt]
y & = A(y-1) = Ay -A \\[10pt]
y - Ay & = -A \\[10pt]
y(1-A) & = -A \\[10pt]
y & = \frac A {A-1}
\end{align}
So this function is its own inverse, or in other words it is an involution.

Thus you have
$$
y = \frac{e^{x-x_0}\frac{y_0}{y_0-1}}{e^{x-x_0}\frac{y_0}{y_0-1} - 1} = \frac{e^{x-x_0} y_0 }{e^{x-x_0} y_0 - (y_0-1) } = \frac{y_0}{y_0 - (y_0-1)e^{-(x-x_0)} }
$$
Divide both the numerator and the denominator by $y_0$ and you've got it.